# MySql Timestamp Index has not improved performance

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Using MySql 3.23 (no choice), I have a table with 5 million+ rows.  I am querying against a column called last_mod_date which is a timestamp(14).

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE last_mod_date >= 'some_date';
```

(Yes I do need all all columns returned.) I noticed that the queries were taking a long time. Often 30-50 seconds. I added an index to the table as follows . . .

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX last_mod_date_idx (last_mod_date);
```

The index was added successfully (took a good few minutes) and I can see it when I run **show index from mytable;** Upon re-running my queries, I am dissappointed with the result. The queries are still taking 30-40+ seconds. Has anyone any suggestions as to steps I could take to improve performance?

Comment: post the result of `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM ...`

Comment: There is not such version from mysql as 3.32. There is a 3.23, which was first released in 1998 and was marked as a stable release 2001. I'm not sure you can achieve much improved performance through programming for such simple queries for such an old version of mysql.

Comment: @Shadow, It's got to be a mistake. MySQL 3.23 does not run on modern operating systems. I've tried. :-)

Comment: @Kieran, Given the specific date you searched for, is the query likely to return more than, say, 20% of the rows in the table?

Comment: @BillKarwin true, but my guess is that the db runs on an old computer somewhere. However, the OP should clarify this.

Comment: @Kieran, the best way to confirm the version of MySQL is to run this query: `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: Hi Bill and others. The version is actually 3.23. Apologies. I have edited the post.  @Bill Kirwan -  The queries return only a small record set typically 1-20 rows.  The actual server running mysql is probably a Windows 2003 box, it could even be a linux box. I'm not sure.

Comment: @Salma A - the result of EXPLAIN * FROM mytable is . . .
table: 'mytable'
type:  'ALL' 
possible_keys: ''
key: ''
key_len null
ref: ''
rows: 5171782
extra: ''

Comment: Just spoke to the IT guys who were able to do a ZenMap scan of the Servers IP. It is telling us that the OS MySql is running on is Sun Solaris 10 :).

Comment: You have an antique! You need to rope off the server with velvet ropes and stanchions. How about the question I asked above about the percentage of the table your query condition is likely to match?

Comment: @Bill Kirwan see my answer to that question above.

Comment: The explain tells me how many rows the optimizer estimates need to be _examined_, but that's bound to be all the rows in the table when the query does a table-scan (type: ALL). I'm asking how many rows will be returned by the query after the condition on `last_mod_date` is applied. The reason is that MySQL (at least versions of MySQL released in recent decades) will skip using an index if it estimates that a large enough portion of the table will be returned anyway. For the same reason you don't see common words in an index at the back of a book.

Comment: @BillKarwin do you know if 3.23 supported USE INDEX ?

Comment: @ysth, USE INDEX won't help the case I described. FORCE INDEX would help persuade the optimizer that a table-scan is worse than using an index. Both of these optimizer hints were added in MySQL 3.23.12, according to the manual I have stashed away.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'mytable';`  How much RAM on the machine?  What is the value of `key_buffer_size`?

Comment: (For others watching:  3.23 was replaced by 4.0 in about 2001.  "Engines" had not been implemented, so they are using MyISAM.)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a kind of fix as follows.

All the tables I am interested in have an Id integer column. This is the primary key. I noticed that when I added the Id to a where clause, the results improved. So for now, I have added the concept of an Id threshold to my code for each table I query. For a table with 5.7m rows, I know I am not interested in the first 5m rows. In this case I would set my threshold to 5000000. My queries now look like this

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Id > some_threshold and last_mod_date >= 'some_date';
```

My code runs 5 of these type of queries. The entire operation has gone from minutes down to 7-10 seconds.